# Get folder path to QGIS processing scripts from PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Where is stored path to processing scripts folder in PyQGIS?

Version of QGIS is 3.16.

I want to get this path by Python script.

[image: Path in QGIS GUI]

I suppose then, is stored in processing object:

```
from qgis import processing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is:

```
from processing.core.ProcessingConfig import ProcessingConfig
print(ProcessingConfig.getSetting('SCRIPTS_FOLDERS'))
```

is simple and works at Python Console (opened QGIS project)

Answer (score 6):

If you have not changed the default path, you can recreate it using the **path of your profile** using [qgisSettingsDirPath](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsApplication.html#a89ad50b0d0fd60ccae803f22f6c5cf46) method from the **QgsApplication** class.

```py
user_directory = QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath()
print(user_directory) 
# C:/Users/vaclav/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/

processing_directory = os.path.join(user_directory,'processing/scripts')
print(processing_directory) 
# C:/Users/vaclav/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/processing/scripts
```

Comment: Your solution is good, and works, thank you

Comment: If you are satisfied, you can validate it in order to mark the subject as resolved.